# HTML5 Video Playback Rate

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm trying to use a drop down window to be able to change the rate of which a video is playing at.

I've added the options on markup here:

```
        <select id="playBackRateDrop">
            <option>0.5</option>
            <option selected= "selected">1</option>
            <option>1.5</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
```

Added a variable to getElementById here `var playRate= document.getElementById("playBackRateDrop");`

Added a actionListener to the dropdown window `playRate.addEventListener("select", setPlaySpeed);`

And created a function here

```
function setPlaySpeed() {
        var rate= playRate.options[selectedIndex].value;
        video.playbackRate= rate;
    }
```

For some reason, the selecting an option from the dropdown doesn't change anything, the video plays as normal.

Comment: But what's the problem?

Comment: Changing the dropdown selection seems to do nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should listen for the event [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) not `select`:

```
playRate.addEventListener("change", setPlaySpeed);
```

Furthermore, you should use `playRate.value` to get the value of the select. Then use `parseFloat` to get the float value of the returned string. This results in the following function:

```
function setPlaySpeed() {
    var rate= playRate.value;
    video.playbackRate= parseFloat(rate);
}
```

Comment: Didn't solve it :/ I thought that was the problem too and have been trying different events but nothing worked. Could I be reading the dropdown values incorrectly?

Comment: That should do it.

Comment: Thanks for your help mate!