# How to increase YouTube video playback rate using setPlaybackRate in Selenium with Python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, html5-video, playback

The objective is to change the HTML video  playback rate before the event `click` with Selenium.
There are several thread discussing about the request such as [OP1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40617585/6446053) and there were two suggestions;

From the [OP1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40617585/6446053), [Jeremy Visser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10839/jeremy-visser) suggested to change the attribute directly, which is as below

```
document.querySelector('video').defaultPlaybackRate = 2.0;
```

While [Armel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7810468/armel) on the hand suggested as shown at the code snippet below

```
var vid = document.getElementById("video1");


function fastPlaySpeed() { 
    vid.playbackRate = 2;}
```

As suggested by [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61305625/6446053), the approach by [Armel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7810468/armel) can be emulated as below,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"\Browsers\chromedriver.exe",
                           options=chrome_options)


browser.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXbfZL5kttM")

WebDriverWait(browser, 70).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Play']"))).click()

print('Complete play')

javascript_to_execute = 'document.getElementById("video1").playbackRate = 2'
webdriver.execute_script(javascript_to_execute))
```

However, it seems that YouTube have different `ElementById` for different video hence make the `js` approach not working as intended.

Apparently YouTube have specific function: `player.setPlaybackRate(suggestedRate:Number):Void` to do this. This function sets the suggested playback rate for the current video  [iFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#setPlaybackRate).

However, I dont have the adequate knowledge on how to integrate `setPlaybackRate(suggestedRate:Number)` in my code snippet. Appreciate if someone can shed some light on how to utilize the `setPlaybackRate` for this particular case.

Thanks in advance for the time taken entertain this request.

Edit 4:

-- Dirty workaround:
a) Install the extension `Video Speed Controller`: Only applicable for Chrome browser.
b) Using  Default Chrome Profile to load the extension as discussed from [OP6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60048530/6446053), or you can load also via Selenium as discus in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59427719/6446053).

Edit 3:

This [OP4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41569037/6446053) suggested postMessage on iframe to pass setPlaybackRate command with rate in argument. But still the question is where to place this?

```
var playbackRate = 2;
var data = {event: 'command', func: 'setPlaybackRate', args: [playbackRate, true]};
var message = JSON.stringify(data);
$('#iframe1')[0].contentWindow.postMessage(message, '*');
```

Edit 2:

Apparently YouTube have specific function: `player.setPlaybackRate(suggestedRate:Number):Void` to do this. This function sets the suggested playback rate for the current video  [iFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#setPlaybackRate).

Edit 1:

My understanding as commented by Greg Burghardt

```
    WebDriverWait(browser, 70).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Play']"))).click()

    print('Complete play')

JavascriptExecutor js;
js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("vid.playbackRate = 2;");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use JavaScript with Selenium WebDriver Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430773/how-to-use-javascript-with-selenium-webdriver-java)

Comment: Hi @GregBurghardt, thanks for the prompt reply but the thread you mentioned above does not explicitly address about the playback rate problem.

Comment: Simply replace the JavaScript the code in `ExecuteScript(...)` with the code you need to alter the playback rate.

Comment: Hi @Greg, then where should I put the java script? on its own file or inside the main Python file?

Comment: As a string argument to the executeScript method.

Comment: Hi @GregBurghardt, are you suggesting something like the Edit 1, i made above? This changes was made according to the suggestion from  Petr Janeček: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11439939/6446053

Comment: I'll post an answer. Also, you wrote Java. The Python and Java APIs are the same, but be sure to translate the programing languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call execute_script on the web driver object:

```
javascript_to_execute = 'document.getElementById("video1").playbackRate = 2'
webdriver.execute_script(javascript_to_execute))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Greg. Just to confirm, the first line is the Java script is it? And say in other application where I have a js that is longer than 1 line, should I wrap all the js syntax inside the double quotes also? Anyhow, thanks for replying. And I believe my question in this comment required other thread. I have to play around with your suggestion as YouTube does not the ID element with name video1.

Comment: @balandongiv: I updated my answer. Hope this clarifies things.

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for the new suggestion, and sorry for the late response. But I still unable to change the playback rate as per your suggestion.